# I try to use Ramda for deleted the files with file deleted=null

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

From a mongo collection I have a deleted field, this field is null or has a date, I am trying to get only the documents whose deleted is with date, or in other words, to eliminate those whose deleted: null, for this I am using ramda but it only returns all the documents.

```
 , deletedFilesList () {
  return reject(equals(null))(this.rows);
}
```

Any idea??

Comment: Just `return this.rows.filter(r => r.deleted !== null)`, there's no need to use Ramda.

Comment: thanks ! but I want whit Ramda, I know filter mode in js but thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Ramda approach, you'll need a predicate that looks at a given prop:

```
return filter(propSatisfies(is(String), 'deleted'))(this.rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reject all items which their `deleted` prop is equal to `null`:

```js
const { reject, propEq } = R

const fn = reject(propEq(null, 'deleted'))

const rows = [{ id: 1, deleted: null }, { id: 2, deleted: Date.now() }, { id: 3, deleted: null }];

const result = fn(rows)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.29.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-5x/n+aOg68Z+O/mq3LW2pC2CvEBSgLl5aLlOJa87AlYM1K8b8qsZ7NTHLe3Hu56aS2W0rgEgVCFA3RM12IXAGw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also Ramda has `isNil` or [`isNotNil`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#isNotNil), therefore you could use something like:

```
R.filter(R.propSatisfies(R.isNil, 'deleted'), documents)
```

---

Although a bit outside of your original ask, if you are working with Mongo, it could be beneficial to add this condition as part of your database query to optimise your program...

```
db.collection('files').find({
  deleted: { $exists: false }
});
```

- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields